# Debian странности WiFi

Tags: debian

Установил debian с gnome.аплет network manager, не искал беспроводные точки доступа, установил wicd - тоже нет результата. Через ifconfig, iwlist scan подключился через консоль к wifi, но несмотря на это, аплет все равно никаких сетей не отображал.

В итоге заменил в `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` и в `/etc/network/interfaces` название интерфейса wlan0 на ath0 и все заработало. Почему с wlan0 не работало? (Кстати такая же проблема была в ubuntu: в консоли команда iwlist scan не работала с wlan0.)

Answer (score 1):

Ну просто драйвер вашего Atheros wifi-адаптера так именует сетевые интерфейсы.. если я не ошибаюсь, то это такое старое именование.. так делали в старых ядрах. В новых ядрах atheros-драйвер создаёт wlanX-имена.